# Dart - how to mock a method that returns a future

Tags: dart, dart-async, dart-unittest

I have a class that defines a method that returns a Future. The Future contains a list of class that also return a future.

```dart
    class User{
      Future<List<Album>> albums(){

      };
    }
    class Album{
      Future<List<Photos>> photos(){
      }
    };
```

What is the best way to mock the method in these classes when testing another class?

The class I am trying to test looks a bit like

```dart
class Presenter {
   Presenter( User user){
       user.albums().then( _processAlbums);
   }
   _processAlbums(List<Album> albums) {
      albums.forEach( (album)=>album.photos.then( _processPhotos));
  }
  _processPhotos(List<Photo> photos) {
     ....stuff
  }
}
```

I tried writing a unit test like this

```dart
class MockUser extends Mock implements User{}
class MockAlbum extends Mock implements Album{}
class MockPhoto extends Mock implements Photo{}

class MockFutureList<T> extends Mock implements Future<T>{

  MockFutureList( List<T> items){
    when( callsTo( "then")).thenReturn( items);
  }
}

void main(){

  test("constuctor should request the albums from the user ",(){

    MockUser user = new MockUser();

    MockAlbum album = new MockAlbum();
    List<Album> listOfAlbums = [ album];

    MockPhoto photo = new MockPhoto();
    List<Album> listOfPhotos = [ album];        
    user.when( callsTo( "albums")).thenReturn(  new MockFutureList(listOfAlbums));    
    album.when( callsTo( "photos")).thenReturn( new MockFutureList( listOfPhotos));

    PicasaPhotoPresentor underTest = new PicasaPhotoPresentor( view, user);

    user.getLogs( callsTo( "albums")).verify( happenedOnce);
    album.getLogs( callsTo( "photos")).verify( happenedOnce);

  });
}
```

This allowed me to test that the constructor called the user.photos() method, but not that the album.photos() method was called.

I am not sure that mocking a Future is a good idea - Would it not be better to create a 'real' Future that contains a list of Mocks?

Any ideas would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
when(mock.method()).thenAnswer((_) => Future.value('string'));
```

Answer (score 7):

Since you're only interested in verifying that methods in `User` and `Album` are called, you won't need to mock the `Future`.

Verifying the mocks gets a bit tricky here, because you're chaining futures inside the constructor. With a little understanding of how the [event loop](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/event-loop/) works in Dart, I recommend using a future and calling `expectAsync` after you create your presenter.

The `expectAsync` function tells the unit test library to wait until it's called to verify your tests. Otherwise the test will complete successfully without running your expectations.

With this, here's what your test should would look like:

```dart
import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';

class MockUser extends Mock implements User {}
class MockAlbum extends Mock implements Album {}

void main() {
  test("constuctor should request the albums from the user ", () {
    var user = new MockUser();
    var album = new MockAlbum();
    user.when(callsTo("albums")).thenReturn(new Future(() => [album]));

    var presenter = new PicasaPhotoPresentor(view, user);

    // Verify the mocks on the next event loop.
    new Future(expectAsync(() {
      album.getLogs(callsTo("photos")).verify(happendOnce);
    }));
  });
}
```

Comment: I ran a test of my code and saw an error using thenReturn.  

'thenReturn' should not be used to return a Future. Instead, use 'thenAnswer((_) => future)'  
After changing it to thenAnswer it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I managed to do it

1) Define FutureCallbackMock

```
class FutureCallbackMock extends Mock implements Function {
  Future<void> call();
}
```

2) get function from a mock and set it up

```
FutureCallback onPressed = FutureCallbackMock().call;
completer = Completer<void>();
future = completer.future;

when(onPressed()).thenAnswer((_) => future);
```

3) Verify like so

```
verify(onPressed()).called(1);
```

4) Complete the future if needed:

```
completer.complete();
```

NOTE: in flutter tests I had to wrap my test in `tester.runAsync` like so

```
      testWidgets(
          'when tapped disables underlying button until future completes',
          (WidgetTester tester) async {
        await tester.runAsync(() async {
           // test here
        });
      });
```

Comment: I'm getting errors while trying to run this. Does this still work in the latest version of dart? Firstly, I need to define a body like this: Future<void> call() async {}. Secondly, when fails.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with [Mocktail](https://pub.dev/packages/mocktail). This is the [article](https://www.christianfindlay.com/blog/flutter-mock-functions-for-testing) that this is from, and explains how to integrate it into your app. This is a full widget test and depends on this gist [code](https://gist.github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/22af958c1e7045913702402bdfe93628#file-main-dart).

The crux is that you need to declare a Mock class that has a `call` method. Then, you can then mock the top-level function that returns a `Future`. You can use the `when` and `verify` methods with this.

```dart
//Gist code
import 'package:gist/main.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LaunchMock extends Mock {
  Future<bool> call(
    Uri url, {
    LaunchMode? mode,
    WebViewConfiguration? webViewConfiguration,
    String? webOnlyWindowName,
  });
}

void main() {
  testWidgets('Test Url Launch', (tester) async {
    //These allow default values
    registerFallbackValue(LaunchMode.platformDefault);
    registerFallbackValue(const WebViewConfiguration());

    //Create the mock
    final mock = LaunchMock();
    when(() => mock(
          flutterDevUri,
          mode: any(named: 'mode'),
          webViewConfiguration: any(named: 'webViewConfiguration'),
          webOnlyWindowName: any(named: 'webOnlyWindowName'),
        )).thenAnswer((_) async => true);

    final builder = compose()
      //Replace the launch function with a mock
      ..addSingletonService<LaunchUrl>(mock);

    await tester.pumpWidget(
      builder.toContainer()<MyApp>(),
    );

    //Tap the icon
    await tester.tap(
      find.byIcon(Icons.favorite),
    );

    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    verify(() => mock(flutterDevUri)).called(1);
  });
}
```